# 1TB drive compressed shows only 3.8GB, what did I do wrong?

Tags: gzip, parallelism, size, disk-image, pv

On Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon I would like to create a disk image of my secondary disk drive (SATA) containing Windows 10, not that it matters now, directly `gzip`'ed using the [Parallel `gzip` = `pigz`](https://www.zlib.net/pigz/) onto NTFS formatted external HDD (compressed on-the-fly).

My problem is inside the resulting compressed file, there is somehow *twisted* (wrong) size of the contents, which I would like you to have a look at:

[image: 1TB drive uncompressed disk shows only 3.8GB whereas its compressed size is 193 GB.]

1TB drive uncompressed disk shows only 3.8GB whereas its compressed size is 193 GB.

```
$ gzip --list sata-disk--windows10--2021-Sep-24.img.gz 
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
       206222131640          3772473344 -5366.5% sata-disk--windows10--2021-Sep-24.img
```

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vlastimil vlastimil 193G 2021-Sep-24 sata-disk--windows10--2021-Sep-24.img.gz
```

---

### Notes to the below shell snippet I just ran

- Serial number censored, of course (`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO`)
- I tried to force the size with `--size` of `pv` command
- The exact byte size of the whole disk comes from `smartctl -i /dev/sdX`

---

### The shell snippet I just ran follows

```bash
dev=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_870_QVO_1TB_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO; \
file=/media/vlastimil/4TB_Seagate_NTFS/Backups/sata-disk--windows10--"$(date +%Y-%b-%d)".img.gz; \
pv --size 1000204886016 < "$dev" | pigz -9 > "$file"
```

---

I am quite sure the problem is in how I used the pipe or `pv` for that matter, but I fail to prove it. Test scenario with a regular file (~2GB) works just fine and as expected. Can this be an error in `gzip` maybe...?

What am I doing wrong here, please? Thank you in advance.

---

Perhaps the last thing to cover is versions of `pv` and `pigz`:

- I am using a packaged version of `pv`: 1.6.6-1
- I am using a compiled version of `pigz`: 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may just have found an answer to this oddity.

As the [`gzip` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip) says:

> **Bugs**: The `gzip` format represents the input size modulo 2^32, so the `--list` option reports incorrect uncompressed sizes and compression ratios for uncompressed files **4 GB and larger**.

It further states:

> To work around this problem, you can use the following command to discover a large uncompressed file's true size: `zcat file.gz | wc -c`.

*On a personal note: That command which could find out the real size, is probably useless on very large files like 1TB is as I cannot really imagine where it would uncompress such file in the first place. Secondly, it would take ages. And even if space is not an issue, then on SSDs there is the wear problem, etc.*

It is clear `gzip` is actually causing the problem. And it will not go away. **In effect, it will cause the decompression progress to be impossible to watch.** (Without feeding `pv` the size, of course.)

---

### So is there any viable solution?

Sadly, I have found nothing so far. I just tried the [Parallel `bzip2`](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/) (from Ubuntu focal universe directly), and it also reports invalid file size (202 GB this time). I need it relatively fast done, so these were my candidates. If I do not find any other fast alternative, I will stick with `gzip` for it is the fastest.

---

### Example with start / finish in color :)

```sh
# UPDATED on 2021-sep-25 03:00 AM
# SATA disk backup using Parallel `gzip` = `pigz` (compiled version 2.6)
tput bold; tput setaf 2; printf '%s' 'Start : '; date; printf '\n'; tput sgr0; \
gz_date=$(date +%Y-%b-%d | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'); \
gz_disk=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_870_QVO_1TB_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO; \
gz_file=/media/vlastimil/4TB_Seagate_Ext4/Backups/sata-disk--windows10--"$gz_date".img.gz; \
pv --size 1000204886016 < "$gz_disk" | pigz -9 > "$gz_file"; \
printf '\n'; tput bold; tput setaf 2; printf '%s' 'Finish: '; date; tput sgr0;
```

---

[A list of my compressor candidates vs their speed can be found here.](https://linuxreviews.org/Comparison_of_Compression_Algorithms) But if it ever disappears, here is a screenshot (click to enlarge):

[image: list of compressor programs and comparison of their speed]

Comment: If all you want is progress during unpack, just use `pv` on the compressed data as you feed it into the decompressor. It will not be entirely accurate, but should give you a rough idea. You can also use [ntfsclone](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ntfsclone.8.html) to omit unallocated blocks from the backup, that would further shrink the backup side, and if you are using a sparse-file aware compression tool such as `xz`, then the amount of compressed data processed is a better predictor for remaining time than the amount of uncompressed data.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak, yes -- my point was that it's sparse file aware, which is what you want for compressing file system images because it can skip the unused space when unpacking, which should save a lot of time on its own if the file system isn't close to full.

Comment: @SimonRichter As I said it is so slow I would never use it again. Cheers.